Inverse function, which is the variable?
I have trouble understanding which is the variable in an inverse function.
Given $y = f(x)$
$f(x) = 3x$
is the inverse $f^-1(y) = \frac 13 y$
or $f^-1(y) = \frac 13 x$
and why?

@Jen: Are you familiar with the concepts of "independent variable" (also know as "domain variable"), and "dependent variable" (also known as "range variable")?

@LeeMosher I do but I'm still at the beginning with functions.

@LeeMosher - I hope you don't mind, but I threw your comment into my answer, as it seemed useful.

Not at all, that's fine.

Which variable you use to define a function is somewhat arbitrary, so saying
$$f(x) = 3x$$
is the same thing as saying
$$f(z) = 3z$$
or even
$$f(y) = 3y$$
With that said, to help the reader it's pretty common to pick, and stick with, different variables to represent different sets of numbers. And a really common one is "$x$ are the values we apply our function $f$ to, and $y$ represents the values we get". When you write $y=f(x)$ you set up that expectation.
[LeeMosher, in a comment, reminds us that these are sometimes called '"independent variable" (also know as "domain variable"), and "dependent variable" (also known as "range variable")"'.]
With that in place it is traditional (because $f^{-1}$ maps in the opposite direction to $f$) to have $f^{-1}$ take in $y$'s and output $x$'s, i.e.
$$ x = f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{3}y$$
although you could also write that as $ f^{-1}(z) = \frac{1}{3}z$, or even $ f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{3}x$, although with that last one you are giving up using particular variables to help your reader understand what's going on.
$ f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{3}x$ does not mean the same thing. And while you could set up some different situation where it could be valid, it's almost nonsensical, and certainly not what you want to use here.

I often make this point by not using letters for the variable names at all. So I'd write something like $$f(\clubsuit) = 3\clubsuit.$$ In practice I use a squiggle instead of $\clubsuit$. I also point out that you can replace the squiggle by not only a variable but even by a formula. Even some advanced math students don't recognize the power of this rather simple and fundamental principle and don't  use it when they should.

Nice way to drive the point home. I'd probably use Russian letters, $f(Я) = 3Я$, because I gotta find a way to make use of all that time spent learning Russian cursive.

A function is the relation between the input and the input. The functions
$$f(x) = 2x, \quad g(y) = 2y, \quad H_{\beta,i}^{(2)}(\omega) = 2 \omega$$
are all the same functions, called by different names : they are the multiplication by 2. The inputs, $x$, $y$ and $\omega$, are meaningless by themselves. What is relevant is the relation between left hand side and right hand side.
If $f(x) = 3x$, then $f$ is the function multiplication by 3. The inverse function $f^{-1}$ is defined as that function which cancels $f$ (provided $f$ is bijective), in the sense that, for all $y$ (or $x$, or however you want to call it)
$$f(f^{-1}(y)) = y.$$
In other words, if $x = f^{-1}(y)$, then $x$ is by definition the solution of the equation $f(x) = y$.
Thus in your case for any $y\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
&f(f^{-1}(y)) &=& y \qquad \textit{Def. of $f^{-1}$}\\
\iff \quad &3f^{-1}(y) &=&y \qquad \textit{Def. of $f$}\\
\iff \quad &f^{-1}(y) &=& \frac{y}{3}.\end{array}$$
This function is division by 3. This is indeed the inverse operation of multiplication by 3.

The choice of what letter to use as a variable as input to a function is arbitrary and can be anything.
To define $f(x) = 3x$ can be just as legitimately defined with $f(w)= 3w$ or $f(\alpha) = 3\alpha$ or $f((\text{harold, the big red dog}))= 3(\text{harold, the big red dog})$.
And, spoiler alert, $f^{-1}(x) = \frac 13x$ can be written as $f^{-1}(geeblegooble)=\frac 13 geeblegooble$.
The use of a second variable in $y=f(x)$ is just to teach the idea of "graphing"; "we measure the input value along the $x$-axis and resulting output we measure along the $y$-axis".  In other words: by convention, $x$=input while $y$= output.
When we teach the idea of finding inverse by saying:
Start with $y =f(x) = 3x$ and solve for $x$ so $y = 3x$ so $x = \frac 13 y$ so $x = f^{-1}(y) = \frac 13y$ and then because they are just variable, we can replace $y$ with anything so we replace it with $x$ so $f^{-1}(x) = \frac 13 x$...
all that is just a "trick" to make teaching and caclulating easier.  But it's justifiable.  If $y=f(x)=3x$ is looking at the input along the $x$ axis and seeing the output along the $y$ axis.  Then $x = f^{-1}(y)=\frac 13 y$ is looking at the same graph but viewing the $y$-axis as input and the $x$ axis as out put.  And if we want to flip the graph to look at in the usual method of $x$=input and $y$= output... we just flip the letters $y = f^{-1}(x) = \frac 13 x$.
We can avoid that by saying $f(x) = 3x$ so therefore but $f^{-1}$ is define to be so that $f(\color{blue}{f^{-1}(x)}) = x$ (no matter how $f$ is defined, $f$ is the function that "undoes' it) then $x = f(\color{blue}{f^{-1}(x)}) = 3\color{blue}{f^{-1}(x)}$ so $\color{blue}{f^{-1}(x)} = \frac 13x$.
But... that's harder to teach and, harder to calculate (so easy to make a typo).
.....
Okay... I see that that can be confusing.  So... I'm going to try again.
$f(input) = output$ and $f^{-1}(output) = input$. (That's the defining concept of an inverse function.)
So if we have a function where $ouput = f(input) = 3input$ then $f^{-1}(output) =input = \frac 13 output$.
To put that is conventional $x=\text{what goes in}$ and $y = \text{what goes out}$ and $y = \text{what goes out} = f(\text{what goes in}) = f(x)$ notation then...
What is going IN is the ouput and what is going out is the INput.
So $input =\text{what's going out}=f^{-1}(\text{what's going in})=f^{-1}(output) =\frac 13 output $ becomes... $y = f^{-1}(x) = \frac 13 x$.
